# Short variant of generate parameters in for cycle in case of hashmap

Tags: java, android, data-structures, collections, hashmap

I am using HashMap and have found an example of using compact type of FOR

```
Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

hashMap.put("one", 5);
    hashMap.put("two", 8);
    hashMap.put("three", 12);
    hashMap.put("four", 5);

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> set = hashMap.entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> me : set) {
    System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
    System.out.println(me.getValue());
    }
```

And i cant find an answer how does people use short variant of writing cycle FOR and how do they generate parameters for that. I mean this line

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> me : set)
```

Comment: Your code runs, is correct, etc.  What is your actual question?

Comment: *how does people use short variant of writing cycle FOR and how do they generate parameters for that.* What???

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what does "Map.Entry<String, Integer> me" means. How did we generate it? And where did we get "me"?

Comment: In this context `me` is just a dummy variable which will hold each map entry as you iterate over the set, that is all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do i understand right that in the left part of " : " we make something which will save something which we put on the right side of the " ; " ???

Comment: see [for-each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you great man. And Tim thank you too for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use short type of cycle For in example

```
String[] fruits = new String[] { "Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Strawberry" };

    for (String fruit : fruits) {
    // fruit is an element of the `fruits` array.
    }
```

String fruit - is variable ( on the left of ":" )

fruits is an object where all our elements saved ( on the right of ":" )